# How to run upstart as non sudo user

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I have a upstart of uwsgi, I want non-sudo user to run uwsgi. In ubuntu server 14.04 I have two users, `user1`(has sudo access) and `user2`(doesn't have sudo access).

upstart script I have `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf`:

```
description "uWSGI instance"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

exec uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid user1 --gid user2 --post-buffering 1 --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=in_accounts.settings.production
```

I can run this uwsgi.conf as `sudo restart uwsgi`. But I want to run this same command as `user2` as `restart uwsgi`. If I run I get following error:

```
restart: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.140" (uid=1001 pid=41623 comm="restart uwsgi ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Restart" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init ")
```